# What's the meaning of "flag out" in this sentence? And what does the entire phrase mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This sentence in the [Oxford Online Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/flag) confuses me:

> the flagging out of much of the fleet to flags of convenience

Even with the definition that flag means here "*Register (a vessel) in a specific country, under whose flag it then sails.*", the clause doesn't make sense. What does it mean? And is it a clause or a phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, a "flag of convenience" means a flag that offers benefits of some kind.

Let's say a ship was built in Argentina, is owned by a ship owner in Bolivia, is staffed with a crew from Chile, and is normally docked in Denmark. I'm no maritime law expert, so I'm not sure which flag would fly over a ship like that. But I do know that a "flag of convenience" might be Ecuador, or France, or Greece. That is, there may be a way to register the ship in one of those nations and derive some sort of benefit.

So, if there were a whole fleet of such ships, and I were walking along the docks, I might ask:

> "How come I don't see any Bolivian flags? Doesn't the owner of this fleet live in Bolivia?"

And you might answer:

> "He does, but he prefers to ***flag out much of the fleet to flags of convenience***. He pays a lot less tariffs and taxes that way."

As you guessed, it's not a full sentence, but a phrase that could be found in a longer sentence.